# Object references lost after service call

Tags: c#, wcf

is there a simple way to keep the references from one object to another after a WCF-Service call?
Here is a little sample:

```
Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
obj1.Tag = "foo";

Class2 obj2 = new Class2();
obj2.Class1 = ob1;
```

So when I change the Tag-property of obj1 to "bar" obj2.obj1.Tag will, obviously, also result in "foo". But this behaviour gets lost when I pass the second object to a WCF-Service and try to do the same operation there. Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]` on your types. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656708.aspx) for details.